# Cygwin SSH Server on Azure Windows Server 2012 R2 VM giving errors

Tags: ssh, cygwin, windows-server, azure, windows-server-2012-r2

No matter what I am not able to connect to cygwin ssh server configured on Windows Server 2012 R2 Azure VM.

Locally it sometimes work sometimes not. Remotely it never works.

Sometimes the error message is
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

other times it is
Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx

I am very confident that i configured it correctly as it works find on my local windows 8.1 machine.

Is anybody aware of the Azure specific issue with the vm.

I followed http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Comment: Cross reference to 2011 posts; 1.[] ; X.SSH Server setup on Cloud in Windows Azure Platform - Stack Overflow ;; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619885/ssh-server-setup-on-cloud-in-windows-azure-platform ; 2.[]NOTE 2014 user feedback ; X.Command Line Access to Azure VMs – SSH - Distributed Development - Site Home - MSDN Blogs ;; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariok/archive/2011/08/09/command-line-access-to-azure-vms-ssh.aspx